# Multiple ifelse statement?

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a table like below, I want to add a column to data using the if-else command, and I used two command lines as below:

```
table:

 A       B        C  

G1    0.04      0.2
G2    0.02     -0.5
G3    0.9       0.1
```

Codes that I have used:

```
1)
table$DE <- 
  if (table$B < 0.05 & table$C> 0) 
{
  print("UP")
} else if (table$B < 0.05 & 
table$C < 0) {
  print("Down")
 } else {
 print("NotSig")
}
```

`[1] "NotSig"
    Warning messages:
    1: In if (table_UGP2$FDR_NCS_H9_KO < 0.05 & table_UGP2$logFC_NCS_H9_KO >  :
      the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
    2: In if (table_UGP2$FDR_NCS_H9_KO < 0.05 & table_UGP2$logFC_NCS_H9_KO <  :
     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

```
2)  table$DE <- function(table) {
  ifelse(table$B < 0.05 & table$C> 
0,"UP",ifelse(table$B < 0.05 & 
table$C < 0,"Down","NotSig"))
}
```

`Error in rep(value, length.out = nrows) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'`

Desired output:

```
 A       B        C    DE

G1    0.04      0.2    Up
G2    0.02     -0.5    Down
G3    0.9       0.1    NotSig
```

Comment: Just use `table$DE <- ifelse(table$B < 0.05 & table$C> 0,"UP",ifelse(table$B < 0.05 & table$C < 0,"Down","NotSig"))` . I don't understand why you put `function()` in it. By the way, the input data does not match with desired one. Since  0.05 changes to 0.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use `ifelse` instead.

```
table <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "A B C
G1 0.04 0.2
G2 0.02 -0.5
G3 0.9 0.1")

table$DE <- ifelse(table$B < .05 & table$C> 0, "Up", 
   ifelse(table$B < .05 & table$C < 0, "Down", "NotSig"))
```

Which produces:

```
  A    B    C     DE
1 G1 0.04  0.2     Up
2 G2 0.02 -0.5   Down
3 G3 0.90  0.1 NotSig
```

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun, here is a solution without any `if`s or `else`s:

```
table <- within(tab, 
       D <- factor((B <= 0.05) * (1 + (C >= 0)), 
                   levels = 0:2,
                   labels = c("NotSig", "Down", "Up")) 
)
table

   A    B    C      D
1 G1 0.04  0.2     Up
2 G2 0.02 -0.5   Down
3 G3 0.90  0.1 NotSig
```

Answer (score 3):

With `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(DE=ifelse(B < 0.05 & C > 0, "UP",
                    ifelse(B < 0.05 & C <0,"Down","Notsig")))
```

Or using `case_when`:

```
df %>% 
   mutate(DE=case_when(B < 0.05 & C>0 ~ "UP",
                       B<0.05 & C<0 ~ "Down",
                       TRUE ~ "Notsig"))
```

Result:

```
A    B    C     DE
1 G1 0.04  0.2     UP
2 G2 0.02 -0.5   Down
3 G3 0.90  0.1 Notsig
```

Data:

```
df <-structure(list(A = structure(1:3, .Label = c("G1", "G2", "G3"
), class = "factor"), B = c(0.04, 0.02, 0.9), C = c(0.2, -0.5, 
0.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```